# Prevent remote desktop client (msrdcw.exe) from extending across all monitors

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

I'm using Remote Desktop client (msrdcw.exe) 1.2.4583.0 (x64) on Windows 11 22H2.  How can I prevent the remote desktop window, showing the desktop of the machine I'm remoted into, from extending across all my monitors when I maximise it?  I cannot find a setting in the Remote Desktop client that would have any bearing on this.

With the old mstsc.exe Remote Desktop if I maximised it, it only maximised to the screen it was on.  However, when I maximise the window from msrdcw.exe it extends across all my monitors.

The only information I can find online seems to relate to mstsc.exe, not msrdcw.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way of doing it:

Every time I remote into the target computer the remote desktop window maximises itself across my 3 monitors.  However, if I then restore down the window I can right click on the window title bar to get the context menu.  From the context menu I then select **Display Settings** and check **Maximize to current displays**.  If I then maximise the window again it will maximise only to the current monitor, rather than extending across all monitors.

[image]

Note that the same context menu is not available, as far as I can see, when the remote desktop window is maximised.

Unfortunately I have to go through this process each time I remote into the same target computer.  However, it only takes a few seconds.